# How to control WPF Controls using Kinect hand pointer?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, kinect, google-plus

I have been developing a desktop application in C# that uses **Kinect** to detect gestures.I want to obtain the user information from Google+ using **google+ APIs**.

The problem is,as I use Kinect hand pointer I can click only elements like **kinect tile buttons** provided by Kinect region.

I use embedded  browser control for authenticating Google+.But for accessing Google+ using **OAuth 2.0**, I need the consent from the user .provided the user clicks the **Allow access**  button which can't be done by Kinect hand pointer.

Is there any way to manipulate the **mouse click programmatically** or to access the browser using the Kinect hand pointer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mouseclick programically, but You can trigger the onclick event handler manually, like:

```
Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {} // - the function that handles the onclick
```

You trigger it manually like this:

```
YourKinectFunction()
{
    Button_Click(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

It will work just as if you clicked the button with mouse.

The `Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is the function which is executed when the event happens. If you trigger the event in your code, the handler will fire. The function doesn't 'know' who triggered the event (unless you specify it in sender parameter).

Comment: I need to click a button in the web page shown by the embedded browser control.So I can't trigger the event manually..